# What does the age_prepare_cypher() in apacheAGE extension do?

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

Im reading through the apacheAGE extension and im having trouble understanding what does age_prepare_cypher() do. What does this function do and where do i find the definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `age_prepare_cypher()` is defined in the `apache/age/src/backend/utils/adt/age_session_info.c` file.

Here's the definition:

```
Datum age_prepare_cypher(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    char *graph_name_str = NULL;
    char *cypher_statement_str = NULL;

    /* both arguments must be non-NULL */
    if (PG_ARGISNULL(0) || PG_ARGISNULL(1))
    {
        PG_RETURN_BOOL(false);
    }

    graph_name_str = PG_GETARG_CSTRING(0);
    cypher_statement_str = PG_GETARG_CSTRING(1);

    /* both strings must be non-NULL */
    if (graph_name_str == NULL || cypher_statement_str == NULL)
    {
        PG_RETURN_BOOL(false);
    }

    set_session_info(graph_name_str, cypher_statement_str);

    PG_RETURN_BOOL(true);
}
```

This function basically checks if the arguments are NULL and if they are not, it calls the `set_session_info()` function in the same file `apache/age/src/backend/utils/adt/age_session_info.c` which is used to set the session info and clean it, if necessary.

Here are some example uses of the `age_prepare_cypher()` function defined in the `age/regress/expected/analyze.out` file:

```
SELECT * FROM age_prepare_cypher(NULL, NULL);
 age_prepare_cypher 
--------------------
 f
(1 row)

SELECT * FROM age_prepare_cypher('analyze', NULL);
 age_prepare_cypher 
--------------------
 f
(1 row)

SELECT * FROM age_prepare_cypher(NULL, '');
 age_prepare_cypher 
--------------------
 f
(1 row)

-- should return true but cypher should fail
SELECT * FROM age_prepare_cypher('analyze', '');
 age_prepare_cypher 
--------------------
 t
(1 row)

-- should return true and execute cypher command
SELECT * FROM age_prepare_cypher('analyze', 'MATCH (u) RETURN (u)');
 age_prepare_cypher 
--------------------
 t
(1 row)


-- should return true but cypher should fail
SELECT * FROM age_prepare_cypher('analyze', '$$ $$');
 age_prepare_cypher 
--------------------
 t
(1 row)
```